# Show Data from CoreData

Tags: ios, swiftui, fetchrequest

I have a SwiftUI project using CoreData Database with a Product entity in it. It has 2 attributes, id, and barcode.
Then I create a fetch request that seems to work but will result in an empty [Products].

When the view appears on screen I get the error

***Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1df9bda98)*** on the ForEach and no other information.

I tried to make it as simple as possible and I still have the problem.
I tried to delete the xcdatamodel file entirely and recreate it and I keep have the problem.

```
private struct ProductList: View {
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Product.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: []
) var products: FetchedResults<Product>


var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List{
            ForEach(products, id: \.id) { product in
                ProductRow(product: product)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
private struct ProductRow: View {
var product: Product

var body: some View {
    Text(product.barcode ?? "No name given")
}
```

}

[Screencapture of the problematic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhswM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Before using `@FetchRequest` you must first have injected a Core Data managed object context into the environment, otherwise your `products` is not empty, but nil

see https://github.com/andrewcbancroft/BlogIdeaList-SwiftUI/tree/master/BlogIdeaList-SwiftUI for further details

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did add @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context to the ProductList: View and I made sure that it is created in the Scene Delegate withn 'guard let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
            fatalError("Unable to read managed object context.")
        }       let startScreen = StartScreen().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)'But the exact same problem still exist

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)